# Laravel 5.5 ajax success function returns empty array

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

This question has been asked before but non of the solutions work for me. This my code

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".comment-rate-wrapper a img").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var item_id = 1;
            var url = "{{route('like.voteHandler', ':id')}}";
            url = url.replace(':id', item_id);
            //alert(url); I am sure thr url is correct and it outputs correctly
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
                url: url, // This is the url we gave in the route
                data: {
                    'item_id': item_id
                },
                success: function (result) { // What to do if we succeed
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

and this is the controller function

```
    public function voteHandler($item_id)
    {
        echo "sas";
        return "hi";
    }
```

But it always returns an empty array and I have no idea why it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: u should retrun response for ajax success/error

Comment: try this = `return response(['msg' => $message, 'status' => 'success']);`

Comment: @Jigs1212 I changed the controller function to both `return result(['msg' => "hello", 'status' => 'success']);` and `return response(['msg' => "hello", 'status' => 'success']);` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out in your controller

```
public function voteHandler(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(["item_id" => $request->item_id]);
}
```

**Edit:**
This was actually an error with the request method,
change your route declaration to match your ajax request method `POST`

```
$router->post('{item_id}/voteHandler', 'LikeController@voteHandler')->name('like.voteHandler');
```

or change your ajax method to `GET`

Comment: I tried `return response()->json(["item_id" => 12]);` and the js success to `success: function (response) { console.log(response);}` still not working

Comment: Try to add `dd($request);` before the return to see if it reaches that function

Comment: When I visit the url in the browser directly, it outputs the `dd` result, but in ajax request it doesn't

Comment: This is route declaration

`$router->get('{item_id}/voteHandler', 'LikeController@voteHandler')->name('like.voteHandler');`

Comment: If you can reach it by url it means it is a `GET`route, change either the route or the method in your ajax post

Comment: As this line says with comment, 
  `method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route` , so change either route or the ajax request

Comment: Yes it worked. I set the route to `post`. thank you very much. Please edit your answer to accept it

Comment: Done, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check Your Ajax request like below way.You should try to below way.

```
public function voteHandler(Request $request) {
 if(Request::ajax()){
        return response()->json(['status'=>'Ajax request']);
    }
    return response()->json(['status'=>'Http request']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Parameter and print the inputs

```
public function voteHandler(Request $request)
{
    print_r($request->all());
}
```

Make sure it reaches this method. Use firebug to debug the same.